# How can I use JMeter to authenticate to a SAML server and proceed with performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, saml

I'm having trouble finding a helpful guide or answer to the following issue. Using JMeter, how can I authenticate to a SAML server (SAML 2.0 assertion) and then proceed with performance testing?

The application-under-test behaves as follows:

1. In a browser, go to **https://application_url/login** (GET Status Code 302)
2. Going to the above URL will redirect you to the authentication server, as follows: **https://saml_auth_server_url/?SAMLRequest=(value)** (GET Status Code 302)
3. There is a second GET on the above URL which adds **&client-request-id=(value)** to the end of the SAMLRequest string (GET Status Code 200)
4. Redirect to **https://application_url** (GET Status Code 302)

After this sequence happens, I can navigate to all child URLs of **https://application_url** (e.g. https://application_url/quicklinks) and I will get data back instead of a Status Code 403 Unauthorized.

How can I set this all up in a JMeter script so it works on playback?

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), you need to extract all these dynamic parameters like `SAMLRequest`, `authenticity_token`, etc. from previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded values with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the Post-Processors.

You can use [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) as a reference, but only as a reference because your SAML authentication setup might be different and depending on response types you might want to choose other/better Post-Processors.

Comment: Dmitri, thanks for taking the time to reply. I am still struggling to get it to work properly even with the website you've linked to.  

Using the Regex Extractor in JMeter, I've got the following setup:  

Name of created variable = SAMLRequest  
Regular Expression = /(?<=SAMLRequest=)[^&]*/gm  

Then in the HTTP Request sample, in the "Send Parameters with Request" table, I have: 
SAMLRequest ${SAMLRequest} true text/plain true

This doesn't seem to be working.